# Como adicionar um link em uma pagina e so proseguir depois que fizer recaptcha?

Tags: php, google, recaptcha

Quero fazer igual a esse site, adicionar um link e so passar por ele se fizer a verificação no recaptcha.

https://www.androidtunado.com.br/p/pagina-de-download_987.html?

Então, depois que faz a verificação do recaptcha, que, acontece o erro. Eu adicionei chave do site e a chave secreta conforme o codigo abaixo. O que eu não sei é adicionar o link de referência.

Erro ocorrido:

method not allowed
Error 405

Eu tentei isso um codigo que um moço criou, vi uma outra duvida parecida com a minha mais não era sobre link alguem pode me ajudar, por favor?
Precisava muito resolver isso.

Aonde eu testei: https://www.euhtmods.com/p/pagina-de-download_19.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Conteudo a ser Bloqueado</title>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
Exemplo</h1>
<?php
   $resposta = false;
   if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
      $captcha_data = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
      $chave_secreta = "CHAVE-SECRETA";   
      $resposta = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$chave_secreta&response=$captcha_data&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
   }
   if ($resposta) {
   ?>
<p>
Por favor, verifique a caixa de captcha para prosseguir para a página de destino!</p>
<?php
   }
   ?>

<?php
   if(!$resposta){
   ?>
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validar()">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptchaCallback" data-sitekey="CHAVE-DE-SITE">
</div>


<button type="submit" class="button">Prosseguir para o Download</button>
</form>
<script>
   googlerecpchk = false;
   function recaptchaCallback() {
      googlerecpchk = true;
   };

   function validar(){

      console.log(googlerecpchk);
      if(!googlerecpchk){
         alert("Por favor, verifique a caixa de captcha para prosseguir para a página de destino!");
         return false;
      }

   }
   </script>
<?php
   }
   ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: assista este vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuWsUDaOQdM

Comment: ta configurado so esse erro ao adicionar um link que não sei resolver infelizmente

Answer (score 0):

Tente deixar a tag form assim: `<form method="post" onsubmit="validar();">`,
você não precisa utilizar `return validar()` basta colocar o nome da função.

Comment: tentei... não deu da erro talvez é algum codigo que ta fazendo isso ocorrer.

Comment: $resposta = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$chave_secreta&response=$captcha_data&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

acho que é isso que ta dando erro mas não sei o que por para consertar o erro.

file_get_contents

diz esse site que isso da esse erro.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

Comment: Você está testando em um servidor local(localhost)?

Comment: tentando no blogger mesmo